# aggregation of monit alerts per cycle

Tags: monit

I have a dozen of identical services configured in monit.

When I enable alerts for `check process` on these services and alert condition arises in all of the services I receive a dozen of identical alerts.

Is there a way to do some kind of aggregation (based on process-check group probably) so that I receive only a single alert within one monit cycle?